# Writing Swift 2.0 code inside Objc *.m file

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to use a swift classes methods from my objective-c .m file but I can't get my file to import.

In Build Settings -> Packaging I have: **Defines Module YES**
my **Product Module Name** is **Library**
In Build Options I have set **Embedded Content Contains Swift Code** as **YES**

However, when I attempt to import the target module to my *.m file I get file not found error.

```
#import "Library-Swift.h"
```

Fails to import.

I have swift files. Any ideas?

I'm also trying to use `"Library-Bridging-Header.h"

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "PLAddBookViewController.h"
```

..but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: To expose Swift to ObjC neither the bridging header nor the Build Settings `Defines Module - YES` and `Embedded Content Contains Swift Code - YES` are basically needed

Answer (score 0):

You can expose your Swift class to ObjC in 2 ways:

```
class MySwiftClass : NSObject { // inherit from any ObjC class
}

@objc class MyClassClass { // tell the compiler to expose it to ObjC
}
```

From the [Swift book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html):

> When you define a Swift class that inherits from `NSObject` or any other Objective-C class, the class is automatically compatible with Objective-C. If your Swift class does not derive from an Objective-C class and you want to use an API from that class in Objective-C code, you can use the `@objc` attribute described below.
>
> The `@objc` attribute makes your Swift API available in Objective-C and the Objective-C runtime. In other words, you can use the `@objc` attribute before a Swift method, property, subscript, initializer, class, protocol, or enumeration to use it from Objective-C code.